# При анимации с помощью anime js, SVG path трансформируется не плавно

Tags: javascript, svg, anime.js, svg-morphing

Я пытаюсь создать простую SVG-анимацию морфинга с использованием Anime JS, но SVG не плавно переходит, как вы можете видеть ниже, он скачет.
Кто-нибудь знает, почему это происходит?

```js
const SVG_PATHS = [
 { value: "M1920,349H0V242s468-52.44,960-73.33S1920,0,1920,0Z" },
   { value: "M1920,466H0V359s159-60,960-73S1920,0,1920,0Z" }
];

const MORPH_SVG = anime({
   targets: ".path",
   d: [
      SVG_PATHS[1], 
      SVG_PATHS[0]
      ],
   easing: "linear",
   duration: 5000,
   loop: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 349" class="svg_curve">
 <path style="fill: #000;" d="M1920, 349H0V242s468-52.44, 1160-73.33S1920, 0, 1920, 0Z" class="path"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/57288149/7394871

Answer (score 2):

> *В своем ответе хочу дать общие рекомендации для реализации гладкой анимации и рассмотреть их на конкретном примере автора вопроса.*

**Быстрый ответ** - ожидаемая плавная анимация морфинга начального пути в конечный путь происходит дискретно, рывками по причине не совпадения узловых точек.

**Подробно:**

Главным условием для реализации плавной анимации изменения пути с помощью атрибута `d` являются:

1. Одинаковое количество узлов
2. Точное совпадение типа узла (A;C;Q) соответственно для каждой точки в начальном и финальном положении пути

Выполнить эти условия можно разными способами но лучше сделать это в векторном редакторе

На изображение ниже показан начальный путь в векторном редакторе, который необходимо преобразовать в конечный путь соблюдая условия идентичности и одинаковое количество узловых точек.
Красными стрелками показаны узлы, которые необходимо переместить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Для перемещения выбранных узловых точек необходимо их отметить с
  помощью щелчка, удерживая <kbd>shift</kbd>
- Затем удерживая клавишу <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> поместите курсор на выбранную
  точку и перетащите кривую целиком в финальное положение анимации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- Сохраните файл в векторном редакторе dв формате `*.svg` и скопируйте
  формулу финального `path`

### Реализация анимации

Теперь у нас есть формулы начального и конечного пути. Для реализации анимации атрибута `d` `path` используем команду `SMIL`

```
<animate attributeName="d" values="`начальный путь`;`конечный путь`" .... />
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 349" class="svg_curve">
 <path style="fill: dodgerblue;" d="M1920,349H0V242s468-52.44,960-73.33S1920,0,1920,0Z" class="path">
  <animate attributeName="d"
    values="
     M1920,349H0V242s468-52.44,960-73.33S1920,0,1920,0Z;
     M1920,466H0V359s159-60,960-73S1920,0,1920,0Z"
  dur="5s"
  fill="freeze"
        />
 </path>
 </svg>
```

Для зацикливания анимации, добавляем значение начального пути:

```
<animate attributeName="d" values="начальный путь;конечный путь;начальный путь" .... />
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 349" class="svg_curve">
 <path style="fill: dodgerblue;" d="M1920,349H0V242s468-52.44,960-73.33S1920,0,1920,0Z" class="path">
  <animate attributeName="d"
    values="
     M1920,349H0V242s468-52.44,960-73.33S1920,0,1920,0Z;
     M1920,466H0V359s159-60,960-73S1920,0,1920,0Z;
  M1920,349H0V242s468-52.44,960-73.33S1920,0,1920,0Z"
  dur="5s"
  fill="freeze"
  repeatCount="indefinite"
        />
 </path>
 </svg>
```

UPDATE

Обход ограничений - на точное совпадение количества и типов узловых точек позволяет сделать плагин [kute-svg.js](http://thednp.github.io/kute.js/start.html)

[Пример использования плагина](https://codepen.io/thednp/pen/YGayLg)

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `SVG_PATHS [0]` в качестве значения для пути:

```js
const SVG_PATHS = [
 { value: "M1920,349H0V242s468-52.44,960-73.33S1920,0,1920,0Z" },
   { value: "M1920,466H0V359s159-60,960-73S1920,0,1920,0Z" }
];

const MORPH_SVG = anime({
   targets: ".path",
   d: [
      SVG_PATHS[1], 
      SVG_PATHS[0]
      ],
   easing: "linear",
   duration: 5000,
   loop: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1920 349" class="svg_curve">
 <path style="fill: #000;" d="M1920,349H0V242s468-52.44,960-73.33S1920,0,1920,0Z" class="path"/>
</svg>
```

Источник: [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57289204/7394871).